# Equivalent of limit

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to write such,
I tried to think I can t, but I found no plausible objection.
$$\lim_{x \to 2} (2x^2 - cx) = 0 \iff 8 -2c = 0$$

Comment: Yes, you can because a polynomial is a continuous function.

Comment: $\iff c=4{}{}{}$

Comment: @Bernard, thanks